# How to animate constraints without calling `layoutIfNeeded`?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, autolayout, uiviewanimation

Calling `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` in the animation block causes all of its child views to animate.

This causes a problem whilst scrolling a `UICollectionView` because the `UICollectionViewCells` animates onto the screen.

[image]

Is there anyway I can stop the `Portsmouth` cell from animating in?

** **EDIT** **

To add insult to injury I am animating the constraints that are controlling the height of the `UICollectionView`. To increase the size of the feed, I have a disappearing `UIView` acting like a header.

Comment: Have you found any solution/workaround for this? I'm experiencing the same problem with constraints animation

Comment: @virus - In my case, I made the `UICollectionView` full screen and animated the `contentInsets` instead - However this has caused some other issues - I would much prefer this collection view bug resolved :s

Comment: I'm guessing that making the Collection View full screen and changing it's content offset is the only way for now ?

Answer (score 4):

You can `layoutIfNeeded` on any view, so perhaps consider changing the view hierarchy of your cell to isolate the view that contains the constraints that need animating. So that your `layoutIfNeeded` call only triggers animations on the constraints you intend to animate. Does that make sense?

This would mean inserting a UIView into your hierarchy, and this view would become the superview of the views you are animating via constraints.

Comment: Arh, what suppose we do if the constraints belong to the `UICollectionView`, any thoughts? - I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent hours trying to fix this bug, and finally I've found a solution:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
       // Layout cell
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

I've been using frames, not auto-layout, but maybe there's a way to disable animations for constraint layouting too.

EDIT:

You could try:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
   [super layoutSubviews];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michal, I went with the content Inset animation. I will try to see whether turning animations off will solve the problem for auto layout.